# Scheduling tasks with lowest overlap

Tags: algorithm, go, scheduled-tasks, system, scheduling

In my project I am trying to create a scheduler for handling my tasks.
I am using Golang but I am looking for the algorithm generally.

System definition:
The system is consist of two parts, core system and agent system.
Clients can register tasks into our core system with a scheduling timeframe like 15 seconds. It means every 15 second we are going to execute that task. All tasks process times are different from each other and the requirement is if task A takes about 2 to 3 second to complete, next executing task A should happen after 17 to 18 second (Because 15 + 2-3 second).
Imagine we have 1000 tasks generated and they have time process between 100ms to 30 second, and between each execution we want to have about 15 second delay ( being exactly 15 second is not required).

Problem: How should we distribute these tasks to be able handling them in an efficient way.
We don't want the system to execute all 1000 tasks at second 0 and after 15 second run another batch of tasks. if execute it like it, core process peaks are gonna be high in some times.

I tried to start all tasks at same time, and if anything executed wait for 15 second and run it again. I considered because all of my tasks can happen in between 100ms to 30 second, after awhile distribution will be better and better.
It is working but efficiency is not that great.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you are asking how to schedule tasks? Are you are asking about best way to schedule things randomly?  Show us the code you tried, the answer could change depending on the code you have, for instance a go routine might have a different answer than an inline function call.

Comment: Do you know the process times in advance? Why might a process not execute? How many processes can execute in parallel? Do we need to worry about resource contention of various kinds?

Comment: My main problem is how to distribute these schedulings, so less overlap happens between them. For example solution can be like if a1 starts at 0 second, a2 starts at 0.2 second and a3 starts at 1 second and etc. Imagine a1 takes 200ms, a2 takes 800 ms and a3 takes 2 seconds. I hope I described it good, if anything is not clear let me know

Comment: @btilly 1. process times can be different from each other and even each of them can change over time but we know the process times are between 100ms to 30 second. 2. all processes will execute for sure but the process time may be different 3. There is not limit about how many processes can happen, we just want to keep overlaps at the minimum as possible 4. imagine resources are limitless

Comment: @MohammadSafakhou Your requirements are unclear. If resources are limitless, why can't we have all processes run at once? If we want to minimize overlaps, just use a single-threaded queue to make sure that there are no overlaps. To have a controlled number of overlaps, just use a worker pool. Lots of solutions exist - but we need to understand the problem to recommend one.